# Soap sandbox at https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx TLS 1.2 only?

Tags: ssl, sandbox, authorize.net

We are testing with SOAP against the test url - https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx

Curious if this is the Sandbox environment with TLS 1.0 and 1.1 disabled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the URL "https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx" points to the sandbox environment.  Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

From an email from Authorize.Net last year:

> Dear Authorize.Net Partner:
>
> As you may be aware, new PCI DSS
> requirements state that all payment systems must disable early TLS by
> 2018.
>
> In preparation for this requirement, Authorize.Net plans to disable
> TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on the following dates:
>
> Sandbox: April 30, 2017 Production: September 18, 2017
>
> We are disabling the sandbox in advance of production to allow you and
> your merchants time to test your solutions and ensure you are no
> longer using TLS 1.0 or 1.1.
>
> Please check the code for your solutions and systems to confirm that
> they can default to TLS 1.2 for your API connections.
>
> You can review our [API Best Practices](http://app.payment.authorize.net/e/er?utm_campaign=Developer%20TLS%20Email.html&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua&s=986383348&lid=286&elqTrackId=0207dadfe404455d94902dda41b56fd1&elq=b360ce45e5ac4148941a0a9b4e9e7712&elqaid=575&elqat=1) for details about TLS 1.2
> platform support and other integration suggestions.
>
> Thank you for your attention to this matter and for being an
> Authorize.Net developer.
>
> Sincerely, Authorize.Net

From [their developer website](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/TLS-1-1-and-1-0-Disabled-in-Sandbox-on-April-30-2017-Updated-2X/ba-p/57726):

> As you may be aware, new PCI DSS requirements state that all payment
> systems must disable early TLS by 2018.
>
> In preparation for this requirement, Authorize.Net plans to disable
> TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on the following dates:
>
> Sandbox -- April 30, 2017 Production – February 28, 2018 We are
> disabling the sandbox in advance of production to allow you to time to
> test your solution and ensure you are no longer using TLS 1.0 or 1.1.
>
> Please check the code for your solutions and systems to confirm that
> they can default to TLS 1.2 for your API connections.
>
> You can review our API Best Practices for details about TLS 1.2
> platform support, cipher recommendations, and other integration
> suggestions:

And further down that page:

‎

> 05-01-2017 01:58 PM - edited ‎05-01-2017 02:27
>
> Hello
> @DavidH @Tri
>
> Yes, updates to remove TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in the sandbox are now complete
>
> Richard

So, yes, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are disabled in the sandbox.

Comment: @kevinhubbard Did this answer your question?